# Problems with mod_rewrite and new url structure

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to make new url structure on my site:
/page.php?id=1 -> /terms-of-service
/page.php?id=2 -> /faq

So i made in htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^terms-of-service /page.php?id=1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

And it works good, when i go mysite.com/terms-of-service i can see my page number 1. But i also want to make a 301 redirect from old addresses to new ones. When i try to make it like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=1$
RewriteRule ^page.php$ terms-of-service? [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^terms-of-service /page.php?id=1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

I got an "Invalid redirect" error in my browser. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rules will cause redirect loop. You need to use `%{THE_REQUEST}` here. Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /page\.php\?id=1\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ terms-of-service? [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^terms-of-service/?$ page.php?id=1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: ok it works now:
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} page.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=1$
RewriteRule ^ terms-of-service? [L,R=301]

Comment: Sorry I missed escaping `?` that's why you had problem. Updated one should work fine.